# Android wear app can't connect to google api services

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os

I'm trying to set up a connection between Android Wear and an Android phone.
The googleApiClient fails to connect, and returns a SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED status code. 
What am I doing wrong?

Here's my Activity's code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    int conResult = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
    if(conResult!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Google play services are not available on this device");
    }

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}
```

This is my build.gradle file on the wear folder:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'

}
```

And my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example" >

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You may check my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786083/android-wear-cant-connect-google-play-service In my case when I use new version of Play Service sdk -> can't connect Google Api Client. I should use version 6.5.87;

Comment: As I think problem may be about an android emulator

Answer (score 1):

**Android Wear requires you have Google Play services version >= 5.0.89 installed on your phone**

You can check your version and update the Play Services APK here: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en

Also Useful:

> Important: Because it is hard to anticipate the state of each device,
>   you must always check for a compatible Google Play services APK before
>   you access Google Play services features. For many apps, the best time
>   to check is during the onResume() method of the main activity.

Code to check if Play Services is available (on your phone):

```
// ########################################################################
// Check if Google Play Services is installed. If not show error dialog.
int result = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
if( ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == result ){
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    loadingTextView.setText("Connecting to Wear...");
}
else {
    // Show appropriate dialog
    Dialog d = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result, this, 0);
    d.show();
}
```

More details here:

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit more problematic to ensure that I have a certain apk on Android Wear (opposed to Android)

Comment: @Omri374 Android checks the version for you. 

FIX: Show the update dialog if ConnectionResult is != SUCCESS 

**Dialog d = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result, this, 0);**

Comment: Showing the error on the screen doesn't solve the problem... I have some bug with my setup that causes this not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like putting the googleClient.connect() on onStart() solves the issue:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    // Build a new GoogleApiClient
    checkIfGoogleApiClientExists();
    googleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"entered onStart");
    super.onStart();
    googleClient.connect();
}
```