# Android wear can't connect google play service

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services, wear-os

I have some problem when connect android wear with phone.
I use android wear emulator (arm) & Genymotion emulator;
When I connect from wear to phone my google api client  returns a SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED error;

(First, I also check some question like: [Android wear app can't connect to google api services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866837/android-wear-app-cant-connect-to-google-api-services) but I think my case is different).

Tl;dr

- use play service wearable 8.4

=> connect wear emulator + real phone -> work as well;

=> connect wear emulator + phone emulator(phone is genymontion + installed playservice + updated) -> return error SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED

Note: both phone & real phone have google play service updated;

- use play service wearable 6.5.87

=> connect wear emulator + real phone => work as well;

=> connect wear emulator + phone emulator => work as well too;

Detail:

On android wear project file build.gradle:

I changed FROM (latest version of google play service sdk)

```
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
```

TO

```
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.5.87'
```

=> My problem is fixed;
But when using google play service wearable 8.4.0 I can connect wear emulator with real phone.

So, I don't know what's problem. As I want to update to latest version of play service (8.4); As I check from another SO question, I think it maybe a problem of Android wear emulator.
So now, Should I update play service to 8.4 or still use 6.5.87;

Comment: Its possible that its an issue with the Android Wear emulator. If you check out the [Google APIs for Android release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases), its a known issue. `Emulators for the latest version of Android Wear are currently unavailable.`

Comment: what do you think about: "work wear emulator + real phone"; "not work wear emulator + phone emulator"